# Asynchronous looping through array with an object carrying another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous, azure-sql-database

I have the following array, which consists of some properties and an array with a few more objects.

```
var array = [
    {
        prop1Name: 'Thing',
        prop2ID: 1
        propArray: [
            {
                innerProp1Name: 'Name 1',
                innerProp2ID: 1
            },
            {
                innerProp1Name: 'Name 2',
                innerProp2ID: 2
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        prop1Name: 'Thing 2',
        prop2ID: 2
        propArray: [
            {
                innerProp1Name: 'Name 1',
                innerProp2ID: 1
            },
            {
                innerProp1Name: 'Name 2',
                innerProp2ID: 2
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, my goal is to insert this into a database, through a Node.JS API. I've dabbled with async.js, but I'm wondering whether or not `async.each()` inside of an `async.each()` is the way to go here. Maybe I could define it inside of the iterator function for the first `async.each()`.

The table needs the ID of the outer property on each of the entries within propArray. PropArray controls the rows to add.

Comment: ...so what isn't working and what did you try?  There are many answers on this site about looping through arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through nested array and do db insert for every entry is very expensive when array and nested arrays are large. if db driver allows you to do array insert (which most do), it's less expensive to flatten it out with regular for loops and do 1 db insert.  something like this:

```
var array = [ ... ];  // your array
var i, j, outLen, inLen, item, innerItem;
var result = [];

for (i = 0, outLen = array.length; i < outLen; i++) {
  item  = array[i];
  for (j = 0, inLen = item.propArray.length; j < inLen; j++) {
    innerItem = item.propArray[j];
    result.push({
      prop1Name: item.prop1Name,
      prop2ID: item.prop2ID,
      innerProp1Name: innerItem.innerProp1Name,
      innerProp2ID: innerItem.innerProp2ID
    });
  }
}

db.collection.insert(result, ...);
```

This doesn't have any error checking and existence of inner array. You might want to do that.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Windows Azure Mobile Services node.js api. Thanks for giving me the pointer for this, though. Can't find any resources on a collection insert.

Comment: If there isn't any collection insert, I guess you have to do nested async.each().  Or you can still use method above to flatten it out and just do on async.each() (or async.eachSeries() if you need to do it in series instead of parallel).

Comment: It doesn't quite matter when the objects are iterated over, as long as it inserts the correct top-level ID for the inner arrays. I will definitely take your awesome advice, thank you so much!